# What is the best way to search string in mySql

Tags: mysql, database, string, search

I have a table and one of the column which contains some string data, eg

TextData  DataID   InsertTime

I want to do a search base on the text data (which can be very long),

```
Select DataID FROM Table WHERE TextData = 'bahbahbahbahbah'
```

I am thinking to add a hash data column in my table which allow me to search the data by hash,

```
Select TextData, DataID FROM Table WHERE TextDataHash = 12345
```

Of course, by doing this, I need to check if the result give me back more than 1 entry (which probably rarely happen), then I get a hash collision and need to do a string comparison by myself to make sure I find the correct entry. My question is that a correct approach to doing this kind of things? Or I should just set the TextData Column as primary index in the database and let the system search for me? Will the database at the end do the same thing internally?Btw, I am using MySql. Thanks!

Comment: Setting `TextData` as the **primary** index is a bad idea, I'd assume that `DataID` should in fact be the primary key. You should add an index to `TextData`. MySQL is quite efficient at performing text searches on indexed fields.

Comment: Whilst MySQL indexes *can* be based on hashes (but only in the `NDB` and `MEMORY` storage engines), usually they are based on B-Trees (it's also possible to have indexes based on R-Trees for spatial data).  B-Trees only index a leftmost *prefix* of the data (up to the first 1000 bytes in MyISAM or 767 bytes in InnoDB), so won't help much with long data.  Storing explicit hashed values (in an indexed column) would be the most efficient method.  Handling collisions in the manner you describe may be perfectly acceptable depending on the probability of collisions and your application requirements.

Comment: If you need to be 100% collision safe you can let the hash field be non-unique and use the hash and the full text when searching. This will still give you the full speed benefit of the hash.